# Add Plugin dependency which is not installed in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am creating an Eclipse plugin for creating a perspective and I need to include a Typescript support for the perspective.

For this, I decided to use the open source project on Github for typescript.java given in [this link](https://github.com/angelozerr/typescript.java).

I have packaged the maven project and got the jars and I have placed the jars in the folder called `lib` in my Eclipse Plug-in project and added the same jars in the classpath of the plugin but still, my project is not detecting the jars and not providing me with the support for Typescript.

I cannot add the Typescript jars to the dependencies section because it is not installed in eclipse so it is not detecting the plug-ins.

This is how my project structure looks like:
[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9w2T.png)

This is my [build.properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWXqp.png) file.

Please help me with this problem.

Comment: Looking at the link this appears to be a set of plugins that you install separately in Eclipse - you do not add them to your plugin. Read the [Getting Started](https://github.com/angelozerr/typescript.java/wiki/Getting-Started) documentation especially the [Installation](https://github.com/angelozerr/typescript.java/wiki/Installation-Update-Site) section.

Comment: @greg-449 I know that in the installation section it is written that you have to install this plugin separately in Eclipse. But then, is there any other way to include the TS support for a custom perspective?

Comment: No. You must install the plugins as described. You can then use them in your own perspective.

Comment: Ok thank you for clarifying this.